# Django documentation, part3 understanding problems

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I read the documentation of Django but now I am at a point where I need some explanation. It is on [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/) site and I understand the views but I really don't get how the urls work. It looks pretty cryptic and confusing to me. Can anybody explain to me how the urls work and what their purpose is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your urls.py file is virtual.  They do it this way so you don't need to worry about a static url to http://yoursite.com/polls/34.  By using this number as a regular expression /(d+) you can keep it dynamic so one url with this regular expression can be millions of different polls.

when the url is requested that regular expression number (whether it's 1 or 13352) is sent to the view which then says, I need to query the database for a Poll that has a PrimaryKey (PK) of whatever this number is.  If it's found the Poll object is sent to the template by the view.  The template then displays all the data in the poll object.

The bottom line is using something like this you can have one line for a url which is essentially millions of different urls.  I use this same format for a movies website I'm creating [www.noobmovies.com](http://www.noobmovies.com).  I follow the same structure for Stars, Movies and blogs.  Essentially three lines of code has created urls for 10,000 pages or so.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated Django documentation page for that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/

Maybe it will help you?